# How to remove an unwanted badge(object) from wordpress website?

Tags: html, wordpress

Accidently I have added this CLEF badge on my wordpress website and now it appears at the bottom most of it. Here is how it looks:

[image]

This is the code on clicking "Inspect Element":

[image]

**How can I remove this blue badge from my website?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css file:

```
.clef-badge {
     display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Where should I add it in my style.css  file? I can't find the clef-badge source in that file.

Comment: Yes you can put it in the style.css file or your own file, if it doesn't work at first add an !important to it.

Comment: You mean !Important .clef-badge{display: none;} ?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation (15 is required). Thanks anyway.